# Is $\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma ^2\mathbf V^H=\mathbf V \mathbf V^H \mathbf \Sigma ^2?$ if $\mathbf \Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $\mathbf \Sigma$ is a nonsquare diagonal matrix,and the elements in there are all real positive value.

Now $\mathbf V$  is a  orthogonal square matrix,which means $\mathbf V \mathbf V^H=\mathbf V^H \mathbf V=\mathbf I$.

Now there is a formula

$\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H(\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma ^2\mathbf V^H)^{-1}\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma$,is my calculation right?

$\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H(\mathbf V  \mathbf \Sigma ^2\mathbf V^H)^{-1}\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma=\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H(\mathbf V \mathbf V^H  \mathbf \Sigma ^2)^{-1}\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma=\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H\frac{\mathbf I}{diag(\mathbf \Sigma ^2)}\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma=\mathbf U \mathbf Idiag(\mathbf \Sigma ^2) \frac{\mathbf I}{diag(\mathbf \Sigma ^2)}  \mathbf V^H\mathbf V =\mathbf U ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the question doesn't make sense, but to answer the question in the prompt: NO.  If you have $VD^2V^T$ this will not in general equal $VV^TD^2$.  As you said, $V$ is orthogonal hence satisfying $VV^T = I$.  A counterexample to $VD^2V^T = VV^TD^2 = D^2$:

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array} \right ]\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
-1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left  [\begin{array}{cc}
3/2 &1/2 \\
1/2 &3/2 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$